# Windows runs fine Ubuntu freezes randomly

Tags: freeze, performance, 16.10

I have a dedicated harddisk which I use solely for Ubuntu 16.10.

The computer freezes seemingly randomly (it doesn't appear to be related to running a certain/specific task nor around the same time).

Sometimes it takes an hour to freeze, but it WILL freeze at some point within two days max even if I just leave it there on the desktop without running any task at all.

By "freezing" I mean no keyboard response and the monitor stays on but nothing moves not even the cursor and I have to shutdown the computer by keeping the power button pushed down for a few seconds.

What can I do to troubleshoot this and find what is at fault? like which logs to create (and how to create them) or check?

Thanks.

Comment: I have recently upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 and I'm having the same issue (not sure it's related to the upgrade though, it could be a coincidence). No clue what it could be. I can't even launch a terminal with CTRL+ALT+Fn keys when it happens. No problem on the same computer with Windows 10 (dual boot), so possibly not hardware related. Sometimes the mouse becomes very slow just before it happens. Sometimes it freezes directly. It seems to be related to my user(or some user settings) because it doesn't happen when I use another user on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

Launching the `top` command in a terminal just before the computer crashes, I have noticed a few times that the `indicator-datetime` process was using 100% of my CPU.

**Solution:**
Therefore I have disabled it from **System Settings → Date and Time → Clock tab** and un-check *Show clock in the menu bar* checkbox and now it seems to work fine.

I have seen similar issues after I had identified this on my PC, both in Ubuntu 16.10 and in much older versions. I also still don't understand why it does it with one of my users, but not with other users on the same computer.